# Corner stone giving me error when clicking on log

Tags: cornerstone

Im getting error pop up while trying to click on log in cornerstone 2.7.10

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for the question I asked.
Since log button was creating error, I just tried to find the cache where log was saving and removed it. That worked fine for me

~/Library/cache/cornerstone

Remove cornerstone folder and open Cornerstone app